# How to use parallel stream in Groovy?

Tags: java, dictionary, groovy, stream

I want to ask how to write the below code in Groovy.

```java
List < String > nums = ['a','b']

Map<String, Long> counts = nums.parallelStream()
.collect( Collectors.groupingBy(k -> k.toLowerCase(), 
Collectors.counting()) );
```

```
Output in java: {a:1,b:1}

I tried using the same but it gives error below:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/cg/root/492337/main.groovy: 7: unexpected token: -> @ line 7, column 43.
lect( Collectors.groupingBy(k -\> k.toLow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors

List < String > nums = ['a','b']

Map<String, Long> counts = nums.parallelStream()
  .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( {k -> k.toLowerCase()}, Collectors.counting()) )
```

Comment: I am trying to use parallelstream() to do create a list of dups and nondups after this : like If arraylist is ['A','a','B','C','C']   then dups:['A','a','C','C'] nondups: ['B']

Comment: So far I did:  Map<Boolean, List<String>> hasDup =
        counts.entrySet().parallelStream()
          .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
             entry -> entry.getValue() > 1,
             Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));

Comment: but this gives dup:['a','b'] nondups:['b']. Is there any way to get the output same as 1st comment                                                                                                                        
  Thanks a lot for help;)

Comment: to have output from first comment you must run through original list and compare it to corresponding partition...

Comment: So can this be done in parallel. What changes should I make the 2 comment code thanks:)

Comment: You have to ask another question. I'm a groovy fan (not java)